# Six operations for (quasi)-coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Can someone point me to a reference with an overview of what Grothendieck's six operations formalism looks like for schemes and (quasi)-coherent sheaves (or derived category objects with (quasi)-coherent cohomology sheaves)?  Do I have to read Residues and Duality? I'm particularly curious about what the two shriek functors look like.  Are there distinguished triangles associated to a closed immersion and its open complement?  What kind of theorems about commutation of pushforwards with pullbacks are true?

Comment: There is no lower shriek functor in the category of quasi-coherent sheaves, unless the morphism is proper. See the appendix by Deligne to Hartshorne's "Residues and Duality" (you have to expand the category to get a good lower shriek). 

Comment: @DamianRössler: what do you mean by "you have to expand the category"?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could read SGA.  But my two favorite sources for this material are [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0573/FormalFeb16.pdf) for an abstract treatment that doesn't (as far as I remember) talk specifically about quasi-coherent sheaves, and [here](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipman/Duality.pdf) for a considerably longer but readable treatement that does.

(More precisely, the first reference has a section that basically takes various properties of quasi-coherent sheaves as axioms and proceeds from there.  If you're willing to accept these axioms without working through all the geometry, that's probably the reference you're looking for.)

Comment: Lipman's notes (now published in Springer LN 1960) is an excellent source for the theory. As Damian said in a previous comment there is no hope to define a "lower shrieck" basically because extension by zero from an open subset destroys quasi-coherence.